# Mobile game engine like UDK to allow iOS deploy from Windows

Tags: ios, windows, game-engine

Is there any other 3D Mobile Game Engine that allow us to develop and test by deploying to iOS from Windows?

Answer (score -1):

This article discusses some of the biggest Open Source game engines for iOS:

http://maniacdev.com/2009/08/the-open-source-iphone-game-engine-comparison

But if you seriously want to develop for iOS (no matter what genre) there is almost no way to not use a Mac, sorry.

Comment: what i'm looking for why udk is able to do that and other engines are not? for example unity3d...

Comment: There's no way around a Mac. Even with UDK you need a Mac when it comes to App Store submission, sorry.

Comment: I'm looking only for development, about app store submission i'm aware of that.